# ViewBag returns null in Layout after value is passed in it from an Action Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionfilterattribute

I made an action filter and set it up globally in my .net core 2.2 application.
This action filter is meant to get a value and pass it into a ViewBag which is used on the Layout view that other views inherit from. This action filter gets the value and passes it in my ViewBag, but the ViewBag still returns null on the Layout View.

This is the Action Filter

```
 public override async void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        SomeAppSettingClass = new SomeAppSettingClass()
        {
            token = configuration.GetValue<string>("SomeAppSettingClass:token") 
        };
        
        IOptions<SomeAppSettingClass> settingsAccessor = Options.Create(appSetting);

        if (context.Controller is Controller)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            
            var companyClient = new CompanyClient(settingsAccessor);
            var companyInfo = await companyClient.GetById(); //this always returns a value
            controller.ViewBag.Company = companyInfo;
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
```

This is how I used it in the Layout

```
<h3>@ViewBag.Company.CompanyName</h3>
```

And this is how I served the ActionFilter globally in the startup page.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter(Configuration));
        });
```

Why is the ViewBag returning null?

Comment: I just tested it and it's working. Did you try to debug your result filter? maybe something else is going wrong.

Comment: yes I did. I even passed a static string value as the viewbag, still same issue: shows an empty string.

Comment: Maybe you can show us the complete code of `MyActionFilter` class.